# restore old purchased in-app product on updated app

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

In app purchase works fine by me before this happens:

I'm updating one of my apps. It has several in app products. I want to make sure that if a user buys any of them, they should also appear "bought" in the updated app. and I did the following but it didn't work:

1. I installed an ad hoc version of the old app to the test device via iTunes, bought 1 in app product there with my test account.
2. Removed the old version. installed the updated version via xcode.
3. my app asks first if the user wants to restore the bought app. when I click restore, it asks me to login. I logged in with the same account I bought 1 in app product, but it didn't restore.

the old and the updated app have the same id. and the restore function works fine when it's not the case with buying in old and restoring in new.

any idea why it happened?

Comment: If you use the same ProductID in both old and new versions of your app, there should not be any problem. IAP's are only related with ProductID and user's AppleID, not with the app version. So I guess it is an IAP sandbox environment problem.

Comment: When using IAP with purchasing / restoring products you should store locally (with for instance `NSUserDefaults`) whether a specific `SKProduct` is purchased or not. This isn't done by the IAP system itself.

Comment: Hi erkanyildiz, yes I'm using sandbox for testing. Do you mean it doesn't work only because the appleID are test accounts?

Comment: Hi basvk, I do use NSUserDefaults, but this is gone after the app is removed so it's not the problem. and the restoring works if I buy a product in the new version and delete the app and re-install and restore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself, nothing to do with the test account. A new version number has to be given to the updated app, which means the build from xcode won't work, it has to be an adhoc version with newer version number.
I haven't encounter such problem before. I guess apple changed their policy recently.